# Parallel Nested For Loop but Output Results in Order

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

Trying to decrease the the time of a program I've been working on. Below is a section of my code where elements are compared to each other to produce a calculation. This calculation is then printed to the console.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStuff - 1; i++) {
    /*
    [10]
    */
    for (int j = i + 1; j < numberOfStuff ; j++) {
        double calc= stuffCompared(b[i], b[j]);
        printf("%2d %2d -> %.20lf\n", i, j, calc);
    }
}
```

My problem is trying to print these results in order on the console but also decreasing the time it takes for my program to run.

I have tried storing the results into an array. This proved to be costly to performance time as expected when printing to console. I also tried using omp ordered as shown below...

```
#pragma omp parallel for ordered
...
#pragma omp ordered
printf("%2d %2d -> %.20lf\n", i, j, calc);
```

... for the printf but found that it does not always produce the ordered result
that I could achieve sequentially but produces a slightly better time performance.

Any help with this would be much appreciated as I am new to OpenMP and parallel programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to **Zulan** for telling me that I was definitely wrong. I explored further and realised my previous mistake before asking this question.

This answer is for others who have a similar problem or looking to a similar solution.

I used a vector for my calculations and utilised both i and j to allocate where the calculation was stored as shown below.

```
std::vector<double> calc;
int vectorSize = (numberOfStuff * numberOfStuff) - numberOfStuff;
calc.resize(vectorSize);

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStuff - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < numberOfStuff; j++) {
        calc[(i * 10) + j] = CompareStuff(b[i], b[j]);
    }
}

// Print
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStuff - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < numberOfStuff ; j++) {
        printf("%2d %2d -> %.20lf\n", i, j, calc[(i * 10) + j]);
    }
}
```

Calculations are performed using omp parallel in a for loop. Once completed a new for loop prints the results in order.

**Importantly** the time remains 16 to 17 seconds to run my program but now the results are in order.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to do a `fflush(stdout);` within the ordered construct to ensure sequential output. That said:

> I have tried storing the results into an array. This proved to be costly to performance time as expected when printing to console

This makes no sense. Storing an element in memory so much faster than formatted output, that storing the results in an intermediate array has noticeable impact on performance. There must be some other effect at work. There may be an issue with memory layout / false sharing, but even that shouldn't matter compared to `printf`. I strongly suggest you pursue that route and try to figure out what went wrong there.

Comment: Thank you Zulan. I was talking to a friend who mentioned the same thing. Something I did wrong on my part. I'll try to find a solution.

Comment: Thank you Zulan, came up with a solution. *thumbs up*